# How to do pull request on github?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github.

Suppose I have a public github repository, and I want to give my boss information
regarding github pull request so that he can run the same project on his local pc and
also do a code review. Please let me know what I need to do? Is there some setup I need
to do on my github public repo or run some commands? I am able to succeffuly create
a public repo and I am able to get a zip file of the whole project and able to test it
locally. But need to do this with pull request as it is required by my boss.

Comment: I've never used Github, but I ran across [this page](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) that might help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GitHub pull requests can only be sent if you have forked the original repository into your own account.

The most common workflow appears to be:

1. Create a new branch for the modifications. (For example, `featureX`...)
2. Do your changes, push them into the new branch.
3. Go to your fork's page in GitHub, switch to the new branch, click on "Pull request".

Comment: If it's a repository you're a collaborator on, you need not fork it.

Comment: @GregGauthier Well, in this case you don't request pulls, you "just push", or am I missing something?

Comment: @leemes I could certainly be mistaken, but in the shops I've worked, branching, and then making pull requests to merge back to master have been common practice. In both shops, you're added as a collaborator to a private repo. So maybe that's where I'm not paying close enough attention, since he did say public. But still,  even with a public repo, if the owner adds you as a collaborator, you need not fork the whole repo.

Comment: @GregGauthier: Forking is still a good idea – to keep your devel branches separate from the owner's devel branches, for example. Also, even when you can push directly, pull requests are still a good tool for code review.

Comment: You provided good arguments which helped me understanding professional use of git better. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think actually the answer for what you're trying to do is a 'git clone' of your github repository - the command for that is given to you on github above latest commits when you open that repository. Get your boss to run clone on his machine, then build/whatever in the usual way.

Github pull requests are just a notification that you've changed something to get someone else on github (perhaps the project you initially forked, perhaps one that has forked you) to do a pull and review/merge/whatever.